# Synchronized section in async map

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, synchronized

I have a big IO function that will continuesly load data from a folder, perform pure calculations on the data, and write it back.

I am running this function over multiple folders in parallel using

```
mapConcurrently_ iofun folderList
```

from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.1.1.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v%3amapConcurrently

This works perfecty... but a little bit too well. Now even the character output of the `putStrLn` calls are async, which leads to an unreadable console log.

**Is there a way to make IO Actions synchronized or even better a synchronized version of putStrLn?**

Answer (score 2):

The way you coordinate threads is via `MVar`s or `TVar`s if you want to use STM. You can read all about them in "Parallel and Concurrent Haskell". You could do something like:

```
do mutex <- newMVar ()
   let putStrLn' = withMVar mutex . const . putStrLn 
   mapConcurrently_ (iofunPrintingWith putStrLn') folderList
```

Comment: You can also learn a lot reading the source of `async`. It's a very simple library, thanks to the power of stm primitives