# Haskell async with blocking print

Tags: haskell, concurrency, synchronization

I have a list of IO actions that I want to be executed concurrently, so I'm using `mapConcurrently` from [`async`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-pool) package.
My IO actions include `print` expressions, for example:

```
processLink :: String -> IO ()
processLink link = do
result <- fetchLink
print $ "Link " ++ link ++ "has been processed"
```

In my `main` I have something like:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  _ <- mapConcurrently (processLink) links
  print "Done!"
```

Everything is executed beautifully in parallel, but it seems like `print` is also executed in parallel character-by-character so I get garbage in the output.
I think I understand why it's happening - `print` outputs one character at a time, so when it's executed from multiple threads all output is interleaved.

What would be a typical way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44916224/8737306) question - the linked code:

```
do mutex <- newMVar ()
   let putStrLn' = withMVar mutex . const . putStrLn 
   mapConcurrently_ (iofunPrintingWith putStrLn') folderList
```

Comment: Thanks for finding the duplicate question! Please don't answer duplicate questions, instead [flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) the question and enter the duplicate link. If others agree, the question will be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Ah, OK. I wanted to comment but couldn't yet, and I wasn't sure about the flag because it doesn't seem to highlight you can add extra info, just that it calls a moderator, sounds a bit scary.